# Momentum is conserved in the gravity of general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, momentum, conservation-laws

(Please excuse my English)

In **Newtonian mechanics** and gravity, these are obvious.

- Momentum is conserved in gravity action.
- Momentum is conserved in real force action.
- Momentum is **not** conserved in fictitious force action.
- So gravity is a real force.

I do not know much about **general relativity(=GR)**. However, I know these.

- In GR, gravity is described as moving in spacetime curvature.
- So gravity is a fictitious force in GR.

Am I right?

If gravity is a fictitious force, momentum is not conserved in gravity of GR?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/62939/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/360930/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic : Thank you. I will read the questions.

Comment: @safesphere : I cannot understand which part of the linked question is related to my question. Could you explain more detail?

Comment: @Qmechanic : I read the questions and answers you linked(=the posts). What I learned from the posts are : "Force, mass, momentum, energy, etc., are notoriously subtle in GR for a generic spacetime." "Momentum conservation can be defined under limited conditions in GR." Am I rightly understood?

Comment: @safesphere : You said "Momentum is conserved with a fictitious force in the frame of reference where this force exists." What is the "this force"?

Comment: @safesphere : Thank you for your comment on GR. However, this should be clarified first. "Momentum is **not** conserved in fictitious force action of **Newtonian mechanics**" Is it right?

Comment: @safesphere :You are confusing about fictitious force. Assume that a reference frame _K_ is accelerating with acceleration **a**. From the viewpoint of _K_, all other reference frames are accelerating with acceleration **-a**. So from the viewpoint of _K_, the forces = (mass of all other reference frames) * **-a** arises, and the momentums of all other reference frames are changed. However, the forces are fictitious forces, not real forces, and the momentums cannot be conserved.

Comment: @safesphere : From the viewpoint _K_ (in my example), momentums cannot be conserved.

Comment: @safesphere : Why do you guess my thought at your will? Do you know me? Please don't do that again....... What I saying is : From the viewpoint of _K_ (in my example), ***the forces*** = (mass of all other reference frames) * **-a** are observed, the changes of ***the momentums*** due to ***the forces*** are observed, and ***the changed momentums*** are not conserved.